# Interpreting correlation plot from multidimensional scaling

Tags: r

Suppose I have a plot produced in r, as the following:

```
res.cor <- cor(mtcars, method = "spearman")
mds.cor <- (1 - res.cor) %>%
  cmdscale() %>%
  as_tibble()
colnames(mds.cor) <- c("Dim.1", "Dim.2")
ggscatter(mds.cor, x = "Dim.1", y = "Dim.2", 
          size = 1,
          label = colnames(res.cor),
          repel = TRUE)
```

[image: correlation matrix]

How can interpret this plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using cmdscale from `MASS` (maybe should include it next time), so in the original mtcar matrix, you calculated the pairwise correlation between each variable.

If we look at a subset of this matrix to interpret it:

```
cor(mtcars)[c("hp","carb","mpg","am"),c("hp","carb","mpg","am")]
             hp        carb        mpg          am
hp    1.0000000  0.74981247 -0.7761684 -0.24320426
carb  0.7498125  1.00000000 -0.5509251  0.05753435
mpg  -0.7761684 -0.55092507  1.0000000  0.59983243
am   -0.2432043  0.05753435  0.5998324  1.00000000
```

You can see hp is more correlated to carb, as compared to mpg and am, and vice versa, am and mpg more similar to one another, as opposed to hp and carb. One way of capturing this difference is to do dimension reduction, like to put all these variables on a 2D map that can capture this differences, and this is what MDS does, in the plot you have.

How to interpret it, the most immediate observation is that you have two groups of variables that are very similar to each other. One group is hp, carb.. (on the left of your plot) and am, mpg, drat.. (on the right). Another way of showing this is:

```
plot(hclust(as.dist(1-cor(mtcars))))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I believe, this is not a good measure/way to find out the correlation.
I think you must be knowing the range for correlation which is -1 to +1
Where, -1 is negative correlation between  two variable, 0 No correlation and 1 is positive correlation.

Many statistician say, < ±0.7 indicates strong correlation.

So, it is better to go for numeric values whenever you are evaluating correlation on a **data set**, if you are evaluating for two variables then scatterplot is best to get insights too.